# Building a Cloud Function to run this application. This is needed due to: firebase hosting

Tags: typescript, firebase, next.js, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I have made the configuration mentioned here:
Couldn't find a `pages` directory. Please create one under the project root Firebase deploy to Hosting
but he stays at this point, it takes more than 1 hour and he still hasn't given an answer at all

I already tried to restart my computer, stop the process, generate npm run build first, and then firebase deploy again, but I still have the same problem

[image: image reference]